# How to order the display of build configurations in TeamCity?

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0

I'm using TeamCity 9.0.2. I have one project with many configurations. Up until now, it's always seemed to order my build configurations alphabetically. Then I accidentally clicked on the x on the right and hid one of my configurations. When I unhid it, that configuration now displays at the very bottom. I would like to move it back where it was.

Comment: I'm on 8.0.6, but on the right side of the header for each Project there is a dropdown next to the X which has an option for reordering build configurations.

Comment: That's it! Thank you Egg. The dropdown arrow is next to the text "no hidden" and gives me the option to "Hide, show or reorder build configurations."

Comment: I'm on 9.0.2 and I'm an admin. I don't see any text saying "no hidden" and the x isn't there now that we have subprojects.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On the right side of the header for each Project, there is a dropdown which has an option for reordering build configurations.

[image: Reordering option]

Comment: This doesn't seem to be on 9.0.2 for me. I have 3 levels of projects (all hanging off the root).

Comment: What page are you looking at?  My screenshot was taken from the overview page.

Comment: The overview page has it but if you drill into a subproject it'll be gone. It'll also be gone if you navigate the breadcrumb of the project/subproject trail but if you click on "Projects" from the top nav, then the dropdown comes back.

Comment: I find the same thing. You can order them on the overview page but not the "project" page. My work around is to prefix them with a number as it seems the project page orders them alphanumerically.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to sort some subprojects where there is a button called reorder. Didn't work. Ended up having to go to the root and click 'configure visible projects' to get it sorted.